# Instagram API showing error while fetching data

Tags: php, api, instagram-api

I am trying to fetch Instagram API data like comments,Like and followers of public posts.my app is approved and having permissions like basic and public-contents are also approved still it showing error while fetching data from public posts.

```
stdClass Object
(
    [meta] => stdClass Object
        (
            [error_type] => OAuthPermissionsException
            [code] => 400
            [error_message] => This client has not been approved to access this resource.
        )

)
```

Please help me out.Thanks in Advance.:)

Answer (score 0):

well Instagram says
We will begin reviewing new and existing apps before granting full API access starting December 3, 2015. Existing apps have until June 1, 2016 to submit and be approved.

We are also launching Sandbox Mode, which will let you privately build and test your apps using Instagram’s APIs as your app is being reviewed.
check this links for more help 
http://developers.instagram.com/post/133424514006/instagram-platform-update
https://github.com/stevenschobert/instafeed.js/issues/345